How to numerically calculate Zak phase for SSH3 model?
The k-space hamiltonian of SSH3 model with nearest neighbour hopping is given by H(k)= \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & u & w e^{-ika} \\
  u & 0 & v \\
  w e^{ika} & v & 0
\end{bmatrix}
where u, v are the intracell hopping and w is the intercell hopping. Is it possible to numerically calculate the zak phase using this matrix's eigenvectors ? If yes then please tell me how or you can provide the code.
